# How to create this feature map?

Tags: programming, circuit-construction, shors-algorithm, modular-exponentiation

In this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2010.02174v2), the following feature map is used:

$$x \to \vert\phi(x)\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2^k}}\sum_{i=0}^{2^k-1}\vert x\cdot g^i\rangle$$

But no circuit is provided. A theoretical description of the circuit is provided in the supplementary information on page 17 (the image is provided below).

The steps require:

1. Modular multiplication and exponentiation: $$C_{y,k}\vert i \rangle \vert 0^n \rangle= \vert i \rangle \vert (y\cdot g^i) \% p \rangle$$
   But they don't describe how to create this.
2. Discrete log: $$U_y \vert (y\cdot g^i) \% p \rangle \vert0\rangle = \vert i \rangle\vert (y\cdot g^i) \% p \rangle$$

The overall process is described as: $$\vert0^n\rangle \overset{H^{\otimes k}}{\to}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2^k}}\sum_{i \in\{0,1\}^k}\vert i\rangle \overset{C_{y,k}}{\to}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2^k}}\sum_{i \in\{0,1\}^k}\vert i\rangle \vert (y\cdot g^i) \% p \rangle \overset{U_y^\dagger}{\to}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2^k}}\sum_{i \in\{0,1\}^k}\vert (y\cdot g^i) \% p \rangle$$

How to create this feature map?

[image: description of circuit]

Comment: Welcome to QCSE! Please do not use images for text and formulas. For text, use text. For formulas, use [mathjax](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49/tutorial-how-to-use-tex-mathjax-to-render-math-notation). Using images makes the question unsearchable and hinders proper rendering. Also, instead of pasting a page from the paper, you should mention page number and write up *your own understanding* of the feature map construction. Please edit your question to improve it.